# Google Earth api allow https connection with unregistered certificate

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth-plugin

Is it possible to allow "insecure" https connection to load a kml file from server? Because now if it gets https error it does not load kml. Google Earth loads kml but asks for approval, api just does not do anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

This is one of my major gripes with the plugin. It'll only pull data off an HTTPS connection if there are no errors. This means that:

- The SSL certificate must be valid
- The SSL certificate must be trusted
- There can be no authentication prompts

  - Passthru authentication that produces no prompting works fine

The only workaround I've found is to go in and manually trust the certificate on the client's machine. Make sure you trust the certificate in each browser that will be used (Chrome, IE, Firefox).

After speaking with Google directly about this -- I wonder if this is something that can be solved, or if it's just one of the "brutal realities" put it place by the web browser container.